# Cannot access variable in derived class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I am not able to access `i` in my derived class. `m.i` is not working. Why?

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        protected int i;
        public MyClass()
        {

        }

        public virtual void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base dis");
        }
    }

    public class MyCla : MyClass
    {
        public MyCla()
        {


        }
        int ij = 12;
        public new void Display()
        {
            MyClass m = new MyClass();
            // m.i is inaccessible here
            Console.WriteLine("Derived dis");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `protected` variables and properties are only available to derived classes, within the derived context (thus by referencing it with `this`), and to instances of the current class (so if `m` was `MyCla` it would have worked).

```
MyCla m = new MyCla();
int x = m.i;
```

An option is to make the field `internal`, or `protected internal` if you wish, which makes it available to all classes within the assembly.

Here is a [compiling example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6xyyoe).

Comment: @Default OP intantiates `MyClass` in the method inside the derived class, not `MyCla`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Sorry, this looks illogical to my thoughts (Not your learn things, but this idea of program logic). Till date in 5 years of programming, I was under the assumption that I can access it this way and that is what Protected means. But strange, the definition of protected access and its behavior looks 180 degree opposite.

Comment: Maybe it is a little strange, but I guess there is a reason for that (thinking, thinking, ...). I guess it is against the paradigm to walk down the entire tree.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Do you see logic in accessing it via base? We can access via base keyword. I see that these both are contradictory and illogical design from Microsoft/programming perspective. I am not an expert, but I am certain I am logical, maybe you will not be able to understand what I want to communicate, but I am not content with this idea.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, thanks for partially agreeing. I am disappointed that I have 5 years of experience, but I was afraid to see strange behavior of this protected today in console app while learning.

Comment: You can access it using `this`, but you are creating a new instance of a base class, that's not enough to gain access to the `protected` variables.

Comment: @Divine `base` and `this` relate to the **current** instance. When you do `MyClass = new MyClass()` you are creating a **new** instance. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Divine this is exactly what I tried to explain to you in my answer.

Comment: @Divine: No need for that. He tries to explain and help you. He is right in the different of the context, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, you all are right :) I am wrong :) Christopher Columbus was headstoned for saying earth is round, all opposed. Einstein was said, he has the worst IQ ever but both these cases have been the best ever in the world of generations and civilizations so far. Bro, here, I am, I am not claiming I am close to one of those, but I am confident this idea of program is wrong. I leave this topic here.

Comment: I don't know how to communicate my idea. Well I am unclear still, I agree with you. Thank you for the answers, I vote your answer.

Comment: I understand is can be confusing, and I have no real reason to say it is a very bad idea. The c# language team thought it was. That ends all.

Comment: @Divine Actually, your claims about both columbus and einstein are incorrect. They are very [common misconceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions). But hey, if you feel that C# is not the language for you due to its limitations there are [more to choose from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)

Answer (score 0):

The "protected" keyword means that only a type and types that derive from that type can access the member.

You have a couple of options if you want to be able to access that member

- Make it public.
- Make it internal. This will allow any types to access the member within the same assembly (or other assemblies should you add friend's

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
```

This instance only allows you to interact with public members. Thus m.i is not working.

Inside your derived class MyCla class however you have access to the protected field.

e.g

```
public new void Display()
{
           i = 1; //this will work
}
```

Comment: Man, I am afraid what you saying. Have you compiled it? I am claiming it should work, but its not working, but you say it has to work.

Comment: Inside your Display method you can access the field from the derived class. But you are creating a new instance and then trying to access to the field. Remove the line MyClass m = new MyClass() and you will see that you can access the private field.

Comment: You may want to run and see. Thanks. Question is not on private but protected.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get protected variables in child class, But that will be accessible in Child Class method or Constructor directly eg. **base.i**;

```
public class MyCla : MyClass
{
    public MyCla()
    {
        base.i=100;
    }
    int ij = 12;
    public new void Display()
    {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        base.i=100; // Accessible
        m.i = 100; // Not Accessible
        Console.WriteLine("Derived dis");
    }
}
```

if you want that variable accessible with object, than make it public.

```
public int i;
public MyClass()
{

}

public class MyCla : MyClass
{
    public MyCla()
    {


    }
    int ij = 12;
    public new void Display()
    {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.i = 100; // accessible
        Console.WriteLine("Derived dis");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but that idea of programming sucked. I do not agree anymore, its illogical. Why the HECK it should be accessible with "Base" and not with "Object". The MSDN has a loads of confusion in framing their sentences or definitions for Inheritance and Protected access. I till date in 5 years of programming, thought protected means, i can access in derived class. Heck, its a shame for both me and Microsoft when it behaves differently when I am learning this today in VS console.

Answer (score -1):

You can access i from within the MyCla class but in your method "Display" you're creating a new MyClass object, hence it has nothing to do with MyCla at all anymore.

Here is a code example of how to access the variable "i":

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected int i;
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base dis");
    }
}

public class MyCla : MyClass
{
    public MyCla()
    {
    }

    int ij = 12;

    public new void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.i);
    }
}
```